# Why ball goes down when I press LMB?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Im trying to make "First Person Controller" blow up (fly up) when i press left mouse button but my ball goes down

This is for Unity 4.5.5 (my notebook does not run 5.x.x versions of Unity)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class eeeboi : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 6.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    public float radius;
    public float force;

void Blow () {
    Collider[] col = Physics.OverlapSphere (transform.position, radius);
    foreach (Collider c in col) {
        if (c.name != "Plane"){
            c.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddExplosionForce (force, transform.position, radius);
        }
    }
}

void Update() {
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();

    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        moveDirection = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection (moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;

        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump"))
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
    }

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move (moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Blow ();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that "First Person Controller" will fly up when my ball is under it but my ball goes down with nothing moving

Comment: Can you provide screenshots that show the components that are on your ball and whatever this "First Person Controller" thing is? It's really unclear if these two names refer to separate objects or not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `AddExplosionForce` method needs the fourth argument to be non-zero, say 3.0F, as in the following [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce.html): `AddExplosionForce(power, explosionPos, radius, 3.0F);`

Also, try using `Debug.Log` [method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) for debugging. Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, make sure that your overlap sphere radius is big enough, so that it touches the object you're want to push upwards/fly up.

Comment: It's centered on the object (2nd argument is `transform.position`) so the object is always going to be in the explosion...unless the radius is zero, maybe? lol

Comment: I thought that this script is going to be attached to the ball and the object we want to push is located at some distance from it.

Comment: The question is really unclear. I agree that this script is meant to go on the ball. But, I also think that the ball is same thing as the "First Person Controller" mentioned in the question, because I think Asker is using that term interchangably with `CharacterController`, which is a sibling component of this script.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I agree with you too. Lets give the author of the question clarify what's object the script is attached to and what's ```CharacterController```.

Comment: i have more problems after your solutions: https://youtu.be/TY_J4riFDL4